# C++ Difference between std::lower_bound and std::set::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, binary-search

Recently, while working on a programming problem in C++, I came across something interesting. My algorithm used a really large set and would use std::lower_bound on it a great deal of times. However, after submitting my solution, contrary to the math I did on paper to prove that my code was fast enough, it ended up being far too slow. The code looked something like this:

```
using namespace std;

set<int> s;
int x;

//code code code

set<int>::iterator it = lower_bound(s.begin(),s.end(),x);
```

However, after getting a hint from a buddy to use set::lower_bound, the algorithm in question worked waaaaaaaay faster than before, and it followed my math. The binary search after changing:

```
set<int>::iterator it = s.lower_bound(x);
```

My question is what's the difference between these two? Why does one work much, much faster than the other? Isn't lower_bound supposed to be a binary search function that has the complexity O(log2(n))? In my code it ended up being way slower than that.

Comment: If this was some sort of contest problem, be aware that you will always want to take advantage of the lower_bound found in set rather than the generic one (which will almost always be slower)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why two seemingly lower\_bound() same method has different processing time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922113/why-two-seemingly-lower-bound-same-method-has-different-processing-time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::set` is typically implemented as a self-balancing tree with some list-like structure tied into it. Knowing this structure, `std::set::lower_bound` will traverse the *tree* knowing the properties of the tree structure. Each step in this just means following a left or right child branch.

`std::lower_bound` needs to run something akin to a binary search over the data.  However since `std::set::iterator` is [bidirectional (not random access)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), this is much slower, a lot of increments need to be done between the checked elements.  The work done between elements is thus much more intense. In this case the algorithm will check the element half way between A and B, then adjust one of A or B, find the element half way between them, and repeat.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for explaining it to me everyone. I'll remember to always use the set::lower_bound with sets now

Answer (score 3):

After reading the API of [std::lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/)

> On non-random-access iterators, the iterator advances produce themselves an additional linear complexity in N on average.

And I think STL set is using non-random-access iterators, so it is not doing a O(log N) binary search if using on STL set

Comment: You are correct, `std::set::iterator` is bidirectional, not random access

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` is a *generic* binary search algorithm, meant to work with most STL containers. `set::lower_bound` is designed to work with `std::set` so it takes advantages of the unique properties of `std::set`.

As `std::set` is often implemented as a red-black tree, one can imagine `std::lower_bound` iterating across all nodes, while `set::lower_bound` just traverses down the tree.

Answer (score 1):

`std::lower_bound` always guarantees a `O(log n)` *comparisons*, only guarantees `O(log n)` time if passed a `RandomAccessIterator`, not just a `ForwardIterator` which does not provide constant-time `std::advance`.

The `std::set::lower_bound` implementation of the same algorithm is able to use internal details of the structure to avoid this problem.