# Why two seemingly lower_bound() same method has different processing time

Tags: algorithm, c++11, set, multiset

While I solve an algorithm question, My solution couldn't get passed because of time issue. 
But I realized that the only difference between passed one and mine was

> ```
> bag.lower_bound(jewerly[i].first) != bag.end() //passed
>
> lower_bound(bag.begin(), bag.end(), jewerly[i].first) != bag.end() //failed
> ```

I've already checked it with `clock()` and It was obviously slower than the other one.

what makes the difference between the two codes?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int MAXN = 300100;

bool cmp(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b)
{
    if(a.second != b.second)
        return a.second > b.second;
    return a.first < b.first;
}

pair<int, int> jewerly[MAXN];
multiset<int> bag;

int main()
{
    int N, K, M;
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &K);

    int w, p;
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &w, &p);
        jewerly[i] = {w, p};
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<K; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &M);
        bag.insert(M);
    }

    sort(jewerly, jewerly+N, cmp);

    clock_t begin = clock();

    long long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)    // #1
    {
        if( bag.empty() ) break;
        if( lower_bound(bag.begin(), bag.end(), jewerly[i].first) != bag.end())
        {
            sum += jewerly[i].second;
            bag.erase(bag.lower_bound(jewerly[i].first));
        }
    }

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)   //#2
    {
        if( bag.empty() ) break;
        if( bag.lower_bound(jewerly[i].first) != bag.end())
        {
            sum += jewerly[i].second;
            bag.erase(bag.lower_bound(jewerly[i].first));
        }
    }
    */

    clock_t end = clock();    
    printf("%lf\n", double(end-begin));
}
```

> Test Input
>       10 8 
>       1 65
>       5 23
>       1 30
>       9 40
>       3 50
>       2 90
>       5 30
>       5 30
>       7 80
>       2 99
>       10
>       15
>       12
>       5
>       3
>       5
>       2
>       2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::lower_bound` has no access to internal structure of `std::multiset`. It is not O(log N) because iterators of `std::multiset` are not random-access (and you can't possibly  implement it for not random-access iterator faster then in Theta(N))

`std::multiset::lower_bound` does have access to structure of a tree and can be easily implemented with complexity O(tree height) which is O(log N)

Comment: Technically, it's `O(log N)` in the number of comparisons, but not in the number of iterator increments. You're probably right on that one.

Comment: Oh Thanks! so It was differently implement!